# record deleted when link is clicked

Tags: php

I have a link/page 'myfiles.php' which shows the details of the file that a certain user uploaded. But after clicking again/entering the 'myfiles.php' into the address bar, the records are gone in the page. What's supposed to be the solution? Please help. Thanks. Here's my code:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    $row1 = $row['name'];
    $row2 = $row['size'];
    $row3 = $row['type'];
    $delfile = "<a href='deletefile.php?file=$row1'>Delete file</a>";
    $dlfile = "<a href='download.php?file=$row1'>Download</a> ";
    echo "<p>";
    echo $row1;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row2;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row3;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $dlfile;
    echo $delfile; 
}
```

Comment: Maybe first time you go there with some post/get data (you come there from some form/link)?

Comment: You need to provide more information.  What file is shown? Was it just uploaded from a form and then shown? Was it uploaded in some earlier session?

Comment: Perhaps you are retrieving the data depending on a variable that is passed via POST or GET vars that are not present on the second visit? Just a wild guess, I think we are going to need more details to be more specific... How do you compose the query? What parameters are you using and how to you get them?

Comment: yes, the records shown in this page came from the upload form.

Comment: the file shown is from what the user uploaded in the upload page. the upload form is this <form action='upload.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some sort of browsing accelerator and don´t you have a deletion confirmation?

It seems your browser is requesting all links on your page and deleting your records.

If you want to delete, insert, update, etc. records in a database, it is a very good idea to use `POST` instead of `GET` (like a clickable link), so you would have to add a form around every entry that posts the data to the server. You can of course skip this, but then you definitely need a `POST` based deletion confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that $usersess is not changing?  If this is dependent on a session or cookie - you should check that it is not expiring or being destroyed.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uploadedfiles WHERE username='$usersess' ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

  $delfile = "<a href=\"deletefile.php?file={$row['name']}\">Delete file</a>";
  $dlfile = "<a href=\"download.php?file={$row['name']}\">Download</a> ";

  echo "<p>{$row['name']}<br>
        {$row['size']}<br>
        {$row['type']}<br>
        {$dlfile}{$delfile}</p>";
}
```

Comment: $usersess = $_SESSION['username'];